# Check for changed text

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

How to check if the data in all textboxes, dropdowns or other elements was changed after opened a page (want to check with javascript or jquery)?
Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve!

Comment: user `change` event. http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the mutation events
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents

Define a `IsDirty()` function,
Attach the change event handler to the preferred element in the page

```
(function($){
  $.fn.OldHtml = "";
  $.fn.Attach= function() {
     $.fn.OldHtml = this.html();
  };

  $.fn.IsDirty = function() {
     return !($.fn.OldHtml == this.html())
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Div1").Attach();//init tracking
    $("#Div2").Attach();//init tracking

    $("#change").click(function(){
        $("#Div1").html("test");//make a change
    });

    $("#check").click(function(){
        alert("Div1 Is Changed:"+$("#Div1").IsDirty()+"\nDiv2 Is Changed:"+$("#Div2").IsDirty());
    });
});​
```

maybe there are other alternatives available but this works
DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6aVjg/4/

regards,
NJ

Comment: I have other question - I want to add funtion CheckIfChanged() for all elements, which outside the table, that I checked, how to make it?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but this not work for me! I want when click to other button or link (not in table) to make this check.

Comment: And I want to make other - when click the other button or link (not in table) to show dialog (I have it) and when click 'ok' to continued with it action, but if click 'cancel' to stop action.Thanks!

Comment: Code has been updated... it'd be good if in question you post what you've done.. NJ

Comment: Thanks, but this not work for me, again. And my last question is still without answer - how to stop click-event (from dialog with 2 buttons)? I tried with preventDefault() but not work...

Answer (score 6):

```
$("input,textarea,select").on("change",function(){
    //do things
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TripNumber, new { @tabindex = "1", maxlength = "20", onchange ="CheckDirty();" })%>

  var isDirty = false;

 function CheckDirty() {
        $('input[type=text],textarea,select,input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]').change(function () {
            if (!isDirty) {
                isDirty = true;
            }
        });
    }
```